# Photon radiation from condensing water

Tags: photons, water, radiation, condensation

Does water vapor generate electromagnetic radiation/photons when it condenses into water droplets?

I know that gas water molecules need a condensation particle to combine into water droplets. A pair of molecules combine on the surface and in the process transfer their binding energy into the kinetic energy of the condensation particle.  Are any photons emitted during this transition?

I'm guessing that the answer is no. By analogy, in the gas state a water molecule can be excited into a an unstable radiative state by colliding with an air molecule like nitrogen.  Similarly it can be de-exited without radiation by a collision as well.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the case where we have a supersaturated solution of water vapor in air, and temporarily furnish a droplet of water to initiate the condensation process.

The condensation process releases the heat of vaporization, which resides in the condensed liquid water droplet, raising its temperature. For the droplet to persist requires that the temperature of the surrounding air be sufficiently lower to conduct that heat away so the droplet does not immediately revaporize.

The radiation of heat as photons with a blackbody spectrum will occur from the warm droplet, but at ambient temperature that is an inefficient process and so the heat transfer is dominated by *conduction* instead.

Comment: Thanks, you answer is very clear.  I presume that this mechanism will work at high altitudes in the air to form droplets for clouds.